# A column is created by a workflow on one machine but not another

Tags: workflow

I have created my own approval workflow.

On my test system the workflow does not create a column for the workflow state, but it does on my debug system.

Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: what sharepoint version you are using? That column maybe hidden in your test system.

Comment: i use SharePoint 2010 Server and the Column is not hidden (i do not find it)

Comment: Check whether your feature is active and your workflow has been associated with this workflow.
check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662529 for further detail to associate your workflow with your list/library.